# Find out the source file (line number) where a global variable was initialized?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have pretty large `C++` code base of a shared library which is messed up with complicated conditional macro spaghetti so IDE has troubles with that. I examined it with GDB to find the initial value of a global variable as follows:

```
$ gdb libcomplex.so

(gdb) p some_global_var
$1 = 1024
```

So I figured out the value the variable was initialized with.

***QUESTION:*** Is it possible to find out which source file (and maybe line number) it was initialized at with GDB?

I tried `list some_global_var`, but it simply prints nothing:

```
(gdb) list some_global_var 
(gdb)
```

Comment: You can put a memory change break for this variable location.

Comment: With a debugger, it's probably the only chance you have. If it doesn't do the job and the initialisation is that deeply hidden in the macros, you might try running the pre-processor only (GCC: -E command line option) and then do a textual search on `some_global_var =`. You might at least get some hints at where to look in original source code.

Comment: @Aconcagua So gdb does not have information regarding the location of the actual  variable definition?

Comment: It has a knowledge of where the variable resides in memory. If *you* know where the variable is initialised, you can set a break point there. The mapping in this direction works. The other way round, as you ask for, not (such an assignment might occur at multiple different locations, so which one should GDB choose?).

Comment: `info line some_global_var` works for C programs. It'll probably work for some C++ programs as well.

Answer (score 2):

So on x86 you can put a limited number of hardware `watchpoint`s on that variable being changed:

If you are lucky, on a global you can get away with

```
watch some_global_var
```

But the debugger may still decide that is not a fixed address, and do a software watchpoint.

So you need to get the address, and watch exactly that:

```
p &some_global_var
(int*)0x000123456789ABC
watch (int*)0x000123456789ABC
```

Now, when you `r`estart, the debugger should pop out when the value is first initialised, perhaps to zero, and/or when it is initialised to the unexpected value. If you are lucky, listing the associated source code will tell you how it came to be initialised. As others have stated you may then need to deduce why that line of code generated that value, which can be a pain with complex macros.

If that doesn't help you, or it stops many times unexpectedly during startup, then you should initially `dis`able the watchpoint, then `starti` to restart you program and stop as soon as possible. Then `p` your global, and if it does not yet have the magic value, `en`able the watchpoint and `c`ontinue. Hopefully this will skip the irrelevant startup and zoom in on the problem value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use rr (https://rr-project.org/) to record a trace of the program, then you could reverse-execute to find the location. E.g.:

```
rr replay
(gdb) continue
...
(gdb) watch -l some_global_var
(gdb) reverse-continue
```